# Code::Blocks error "rad2deg does not name a type" error "rad2deg was not declared in this scope" C++23

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I know for a fact this code is written correctly due to testing this on my Linux machine. No matter what I have done the error persists. I am new to Windows 10 and Code::Blocks, any help regarding setting up Code::Blocks properly or the issue at hand would be greatly appreciated.

I have no idea what I can do since the code is exactly the same. I am unfamiliar with Code::Blocks and I assume I must have failed to configure something. Any help would be awesome, thank you.

Linux:

```
//g++ main.cpp -Os -std=c++23 -Wall -Wextra; ./a.out
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int32_t main() {
    auto rad2deg = [](double rad) {return rad * 180.0 / std::acos(-1.0);};
    std::cout << rad2deg(6.2) << '\n';
}
```

Windows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <cmath> 


int32_t main() {
    auto rad2deg = [](double rad) {return rad * 180.0 / std::acos(-1.0);};
    std::cout << rad2deg(6.2) << '\n';
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
355.234
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
error: 'rad2deg' does not name a type
error: 'rad2deg' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Why do you include all the extra headers in the "Windows" program, which is otherwise exactly the same as the "Linux" program?

Comment: Also note that [the `main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) *must* be declared to return an **`int`**.

Comment: As for your problem, how have you configured your IDE? What options and flags are passed to the compiler? Which version of the compiler are you using? Are you using MinGW (or MSYS) for the compiler?

Comment: Is `std=c++23` regognised already? It's not yet officially released, `gcc` usually uses flags like `c++2a/b/c` for yet upcoming standards instead (`2a` had been used for C++20, so should be `2b` now). Are you compiling with GCC under windows, too (MinGW)? MSVC's flag looks a bit different (`/std:C++XX` if I recall correctly).

Comment: By the way, you should include the C++ headers (`<cstdXYZ>`) instead of the C ones (`<stdXYZ.h>`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried it without the includes and it doesn't know what "int32" is. I am using MinGW. I've been using things like std::extent and std::mdspan just fine(c++23).

Comment: Like I said, the return type of `main` needs to be plain `int`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work by changing the compiler settings under Settings -> Compiler and changing the Compiler Flag to c++17 instead of c++98 (LOL)